# Referenced assembly can not read app.config

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore, appsettings

I'm having problems with my unit tests. The problem is: I'm using Sitecore. Another question I asked about this is: [Unit Testing Sitecore LicenseManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503985/unit-testing-sitecore-licensemanager)

My problem is that I get the exception:

```
Test method foo.Bar.Framework.Tests.Core.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Sitecore.Services.Heartbeat' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not read Sitecore configuration.
```

I looked into the code with dotPeek and the function Sitecorre.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("HeartbeatInterval") throws an exception. Because it can not read the configuration.
When I add the same code to my unit test .cs file and debug the test it can read the configuration.
The setting is also available in the app.config

It looks like the referenced assembly cannot read the config and the test itself can.
How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

The Settings.GetSetting() function eventually uses Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigReader.GetConfigNode(). This Function eventually uses this function:

```
private static ConfigReader GetReader()
{
    return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sitecore") as ConfigReader;
}
```

So...
Why can't the referenced dll read the app.config through the ConfigurationManager?

Comment: Is your app.config in the test project or in other project?

Comment: It is in the testproject. Build action: none. Copy to ouput dir: do not copy. The assemblies are in the References folder, obviously

Comment: Does it work with a regular project?

Comment: Yes, i got the same settings in my web.config and the code project is working just fine

Comment: Maybe the exception means it is found but not readable because of syntax error. Try do delete the section and rebuild. Do you get the same exception?

Comment: I pulled the web.config from the sitecore zip file and replaced all the sc.include tags with comments and the domains and globalroles to a absolute path. Now i works locally. I'm gonna try to get it to run on my buildagent now.

Comment: now it is not working on my build agent with MSTest but it is working on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the *.testsettings.
When I ran it on my pc it worked but on the build server it did not. Turned out I just had to commit the *.testsettings and include the /testsettings parameter